# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2019-05-13 23:45:00' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to fetch the results of a Test (one of the columns) for a particular day from a SQL Server DB. The date field by default is shown in UnixTimeStamp format, so I used DateAdd function with Cast, to display it in day time format.
But now, If I try to filter the results only for a particular day, I get error as

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2019-05-13
>   23:45:00' to data type int.

It looks like the casting that I did to the Unixtimestamp gives a Varchar value which I cannot use to compare like an integer. But I am unable to get this working inorder to compare the date field.
Any solution will be greatly appreciated.

Below is my query:

```
DECLARE @LocalTimeOffset BIGINT
SET @LocalTimeOffset = DATEDIFF(SECOND, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE())


SELECT 
    DATEADD(SECOND, F_DATE - @LocalTimeOffset, CAST('1970-01-01 00:00:00' AS datetime)) as F_DATE, 
      ,[F_PART]
      ,[F_PRCS]
      ,[F_TEST]
      ,[F_VALUE]
FROM
    Table1
WHERE 
    F_DATE> '2019-05-14 23:45:00' AND F_DATE< '2019-05-16 00:00:00'
```

Results are normally shown as below if I dont try to filter by Date:

```
F_Date               F_PART         F_PRCS         F_TEST      F_Value
14-01-2016 08:23:00   1442418652    1442413364   1442329164        0
14-01-2016 08:58:00   1442418652    1442413315   1442329228        0
14-01-2016 09:26:00   1442418687    1442413586   1443628344        2
14-01-2016 09:26:00   1442418705    1442413778   1451906136        0
14-01-2016 09:27:00   1442418687    1442413586   1442329173        0
14-01-2016 09:27:00   1442418687    1442413586   1442329224        0
14-01-2016 10:04:00   1442418687    1442413586   1442329232        0
15-01-2016 04:09:00   1442418687    1442413578   1443814431        0
16-01-2016 04:09:00   1442418687    1442413578   1443814483        0
17-01-2016 04:09:00   1442418687    1442413578   1443814521        0
18-01-2016 04:09:00   1442418687    1442413578   1451906136        0
19-01-2016 04:09:00   1442418687    1442413578   1443814800        0
```

I want to filter the results only for a particular day 
For eg, For 15-01-2016 I want the below result.

```
F_Date                  F_PART        F_PRCS          F_TEST        F_Value
15-01-2016 04:09:00    1442418687    1442413578       1443814431    0
```

Comment: https://sqlbolt.com/lesson/select_queries_order_of_execution.  You have to use a sql statement in the WHERE clause, not an alias from the SELECT clause.

Comment: SQL, the language, has date types. *All* databases have date types, including SQLite. You don't need a Unix timestamp nor should you use such a thing.  Never mind that those values are too short to cover *milliseconds*, which the `datetime`, `datetime2` and `datetimeoffset` types handle without an issue. Don't use `int` or "unix timestamps". That's the *real* problem of this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there is no `BIGINTSET` datatype in SQL Server, maybe you mean `BIGINT`, and you don't need to specify the variable name `@LocalTimeOffset` twice.

```
DECLARE @LocalTimeOffset BIGINT = DATEDIFF(second,GETDATE(),GETUTCDATE());
```

For the query, there is a lot of problems there, at first you can't use the alias name of a column in the `WHERE` clause unless you're use it in a CTE/SubQuery, then you can refer to it by the alias.

Second, you're passing a literal string, convert it to a `DATE` then add the number of seconds stored in the variable `@LocalTimeOffset`, so the value of `F_DATE` would be the same for all rows, which makes the filter in the `WHERE` clause doesn't make sense.

Also, the part `DATEADD(second,F_DATE@LocalTimeOffset,` isn't true and will throw an error, which mean your query isn't returning the data you provide.

> Invalid column name 'F_DATE@LocalTimeOffset'.

If we just try to fix the query you provide, it will be just the same as

```
DECLARE @LocalTimeOffset BIGINT = DATEDIFF(second,GETDATE(),GETUTCDATE());

SELECT DATEADD(second, @LocalTimeOffset, CAST('1970-01-01 00:00:00' AS datetime)) as F_DATE
FROM master..[spt_values];
```

So, what are you trying to filter here since you have the same value in `F_DATE` column in all rows?

---

After the comment you post and the updates, you can do as

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT 
    DATEADD(SECOND, F_DATE - @LocalTimeOffset, CAST('1970-01-01 00:00:00' AS datetime)) as F_DATE, 
      ,[F_PART]
      ,[F_PRCS]
      ,[F_TEST]
      ,[F_VALUE]
FROM
    Table1
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE F_DATE > '2019-05-14 23:45:00' AND F_DATE < '2019-05-16 00:00:00';
```

Comment: Okay. understood about referring alias name directly in where clause. But regarding your second point regarding conversion, I am infact getting the F_DATE different for all the rows. So now I am confused if my date conversion itself is wrong.

And also DATEADD(second,F_DATE@LocalTimeOffset, part seems to work without throwing an error.

Comment: @Krishna Alright, let me ask you one thing, What is `F_DATE@LocalTimeOffset,`? I think F_Date is a date column which doesn't exists yet there, and `@LocalTimeOffset` is an INT.

Comment: Oh no. Looks like a '-' sign was left out in the code that I copied here. The actual code that I am running in SQL is this. Apologies as I dont know how the Minus sign was left out :/

DATEADD(second,F_SGTM-@LocalTimeOffset, CAST('1970-01-01 00:00:00' AS datetime)) as F_SGTM

Comment: Still, we need to know what's `F_SGTM` datatype, and does it a column in the table?

Comment: F_SGTM is the F_DATE field that you are seeing in the query.. For readability, I mentioned that column as F_DATE here. But did a silly mistake.

The date conversion query is this.
DATEADD(second,F_DATE-@LocalTimeOffset, CAST('1970-01-01 00:00:00' AS datetime)) as F_DATE

This F_DATE is a column in a View and is of INT Datatype.

Answer (score 0):

You need a subquery, CTE, or lateral join.  You cannot refer to a column alias in the `WHERE`.

So, the reference to `F_DATE` in the `WHERE` is to the column in the table, not the converted value.

I am not sure what `BIGINTSET` is or what the `@`notation is supposed to be.

I like:

```
SELECT v.F_DATE, . . .
FROM Table1 t1 CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (DATEADD(second, F_DATE, CAST('1970-01-01' AS datetime))
     ) v(F_DATE)
WHERE v.F_DATE > '2019-05-14 23:45:00' AND
      v.F_DATE < '2019-05-16 00:00:00';
```

Comment: Really? `DATEADD(second, F_DATE@LocalTimeOffset`

Comment: @sami . . . There are some strange things in the original query.  That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Exactly, and that what I wrote in my answer plus the OP update his question after some question I asked him.